# ROS network is disabled

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run the node_manager, on the top left, "ROS Network [disabled]" is shown.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294065/ros-network-is-disabled./) by [amelia](https://answers.ros.org/users/35848/amelia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2018-06-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Run master_discovery node if you have more than 1 host, $ rosrun master_discovery_fkie master_discovery.
If not, do not need to start master_discovery.
You can start master_discovery by pressing on "start" button.

All thanks to Alexander Tiderko for replying my email!

---

Originally posted by [amelia](https://answers.ros.org/users/35848/amelia/) with karma: 18 on 2018-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0